# How do I delete rows in one CSV based on another CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, compare

I am working with two CSV files, both contain only one column of data, but are over 50,000 rows. I need to compare the data from CSV1 against CSV2 and remove any data that displays in both of these files. I would like to print out the final list of data as a 3rd CSV file if possible.

The CSV files contain usernames. I have tried running deduplication scripts but realize that this does not remove entries found in both CSV files entirely since it only removes the duplication of a username. This is what I have been currently working with but I can already tell that this isn't going to give me the results I am looking for.

```
 import csv

 AD_AccountsCSV = open("AD_Accounts.csv", "r")
 BA_AccountsCSV = open("BA_Accounts.csv", "r+")

 def Remove(x,y):

            final_list =[]
            for item in x:
                            if item not in y:
                                            final_list.append(item)

            for i in y:
                            if i not in x:
                                            final_list.append(i)
            print (final_list)
```

The way that I wrote this code would print the results within the terminal after running the script but I realize that my output may be around 1,000 entries.

Comment: If you have access to a UNIX shell you might look into `comm` (also see https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm).

Answer (score 0):

```
# define the paths
fpath1 = "/path/to/file1.csv"
fpath2 = "/path/to/file2.csv"
fpath3 = "/path/to/your/file3.csv"

with open(fpath1) as f1, open(fpath2) as f2, open(fpath3, "w") as f3:
    l1 = f1.readlines()
    l2 = f2.readlines()
    not_in_both = [x for x in set(l1 + l2) if x in l1 and x in l2]
    for x in not_in_both:
        print(x, file=f3)
```

The `with open() as ...` clause takes care of closing the file.
You can combine several file openings under `with`.
Assuming, that the elements in the files are the only elements per line, I used simple `readlines()` (which automatically removes the newline character at the end). Otherwise it becomes more complicated in this step.
List-expressions make it nice to filter lists by conditions.
Default `end='\n'` in `print()` adds newline at end of each print.

**In the way you did**

For formatting code, please follow official style guides, e.g.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
def select_exclusive_accounts(path_to_f1,path_to_f2, path_to_f3): 
    # you have quite huge indentations - use 4 spaces!
    with open(path_to_f1) as f1, open(path_to_f2) as f2, \
                                      open(path_to_f3, "w") as f3:
    for item in in_f1:
        if item not in in_f2:
            f3.write(item)
    for i in in_f2:
        if i not in in_f1:
            f3.write(item)

select_exclusive_accounts("AD_Accounts.csv", 
                          "BA_Accounts.csv", 
                          "exclusive_accounts.csv")
```

Also here no imports not needed because these are standard Python commands.

Comment: I'm new to python so forgive me if this is a silly question but what I would define fpath1 and fpath2 as?

Comment: Hey! Welcome here! I modified the answer - the absolute or relative paths to your files (simple strings).

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! Would I still need to import the csv in the beginning of the script if I set the fpaths?

Comment: no with the commands I used not. You import only if you have to use functions which are not basic Python commands and if the commands are from the modules to be imported.